# How to set exclude list in command line for maven release plugin?

Tags: file, maven, plugins, release

I try to use option:

```
checkModificationExcludeList
```

but I don't know correct syntax:

```
mvn -U release:prepare checkModificationExcludeList myfile.txt
```

doesn't work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Correct syntax for excluding files from local modifications check is,

```
mvn release:prepare -DcheckModificationExcludeList=one.txt,two.txt
```

Make sure that you pass the argument using -D

For files in sub directories, I believe you simply need to give the file name and the path can be skipped.

Comment: I tried the very same thing on my project before posting. I am using Maven 3.0.3 and Maven Release Plugin 2.1 What are you using?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that the path can be skipped! Very useful when the project uses svn external links (for whatever reason...)!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that helped a lot. Just the additional hint, that if you have a multi module project and do the release on the top level module, you can also exclude files in sub-modules by prefixing the filename with "[sub-module-name]\".

Comment: To skip files in subfolders, use **\filename. Ex: **\pom.xml will ignore all changes in pom files

Comment: To exclude all files and sub directory provide the path like this /opt/skip/path/**